# Angular - OnSelected function not works on tag-input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-chips

I'm using ngx-chips, but I can't implement the OnSelected function.

In my app.component.html I have this:

```
<div class="force-to-the-bottom">
  <tag-input [ngModel]="[]" 
  (onSelect)="onSelected($event)"
  (onRemove)="onItemRemoved($event)">
    <tag-input-dropdown
      [autocompleteItems]="items"
      [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true"
      [dynamicUpdate]="false"            
    >
    </tag-input-dropdown>
  </tag-input>
</div>
```

In my app.component.ts the functions are implemented in this simple way:

```
  onSelected($event: any) {
    console.log("Fire Selected");
  }

  onItemRemoved($event: any) {
    console.log("Fire Removed");
  }
```

The very strange thing is that onItemRemoved works properly, while onSelected not fire.

This is my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ye2n9g)

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Do you click on the chip added? `onSelect` is trigger when you click on a chip already added not when you select an item from the list.

Comment: If i click on the chip added it works. You are right.
But what I wanted was that on item selected from dropdown starts the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just confusing between `onAdd` and `onSelect` events. Probably what you're looking for is the `onAdd` event of `ngx-chips`. Here's a link to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips#outputs-optional) for all the output events.

```
<tag-input [ngModel]="[]" (onAdd)="onAdded($event)" (onSelect)="onSelected($event)" (onRemove)="onItemRemoved($event)">
    <tag-input-dropdown
      [autocompleteItems]="items"
      [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true"
      [dynamicUpdate]="false"            
    >
    </tag-input-dropdown>
  </tag-input>
```

And the TS -

```
onAdded($event: any) {
    console.log("Fire Added");
  }
```

Here's [a Stackblitz for demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7kvyp)

if you see the Stackblitz, your `onSelect` works fine as well. It's just an event which is fired when you click on the tag after it has been added to the input. Confusing naming, I know.

Comment: Thank you. Everything works properly now.
The problem is that on the onAdded I try to open a modal window and I get this error: 

ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng2-tag-input--focused: true'. Current value: 'ng2-tag-input--focused: false'.

Comment: Usually, `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` are the nastiest to debug. But most of the times it would narrow down to you changing some value that is already being changed by a library. Should be another question with a lot more context, though.